# Getting bizarre issue with variables outside the main method?

Tags: c++, variables, scope, fibonacci

I have some global variables defined just above my main method. When I try to call the function "fib()" while using those variables, I get incorrect results.

When I move the variables into the local scope of the function, I get correct results.

Why does this happen? Here is the correct code:

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

vector <int> fibVals;
int fibInput;

int fib(int n);

int main()
{

    cout << "Please enter 3 Fibonacci numbers you wish to find:: \n";

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        cin >> fibInput;
        fibVals.push_back(fibInput);
    } 

    cout << "The values at those Fibonacci numbers are(in order)::\n";

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
         cout << fib( fibVals[i] ) << "\n";

    }

    return 0;
}


int fib(int n)
{

    int sum = 0;
    int fib1 = 1;
    int fib2 = 0;


    if (n == 0 || n == 1)
        return n;


    for(int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
    {

        sum = fib1 + fib2;

        fib2 = fib1;

        fib1 = sum;

    }

    return sum;

}
```

The incorrect code has the three variables "sum", "fib1", and "fib2" above the main method. Why does this not work, but declaring the variables inside the function does?

Edit: below is the incorrect code. Note that the only difference is the placement of the variables.

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

vector <int> fibVals;
int fibInput;

int fib(int n);


int sum = 0;
int fib1 = 1;
int fib2 = 0;

int main()
{

    cout << "Please enter 3 Fibonacci numbers you wish to find:: \n";

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        cin >> fibInput;
        fibVals.push_back(fibInput);
    } 

    cout << "The values at those Fibonacci numbers are(in order)::\n";

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
         cout << fib( fibVals[i] ) << "\n";

    }

    return 0;
}


int fib(int n)
{

    if (n == 0 || n == 1)
        return n;


    for(int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
    {

        sum = fib1 + fib2;

        fib2 = fib1;

        fib1 = sum;

    }

    return sum;

}
```

I understand the concept of scope. I *thought* that making those three variables global(outside main) would make no difference than if they were made local(inside fib() ).

Comment: What does *"into the local scope of the function"* mean?

Comment: we would have to see the code that *isn't* working to know why. Maybe you are not properly initializing the variables, who knows. Again, show the failing code.

Comment: Please post your input, output and expected output.

Comment: This would be a great opportunity to (a) learn what a global variable is, and (b) learn how to use a debugger, which will easily reveal what the problem is. I am curious as to what compelled you to want to declare them globally? What did you think that meant?

Comment: I was doing this for a class. The teacher want's all of our variables to be declared globally if possible... I know it's ridiculous.

Comment: Nobody will hire anyone who thinks that is a good idea!?!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to make your question clearer. Nevertheless I will take a shot in the dark and try to respond to what I believe your question is. Think what happens if you move `sum`, `fib1`, and `fib2` outside the function `fib()`, in other words you make them **global**. They will keep their value across function invocations (technically, they have [*static storage duration*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration)). Hence, when you invoke `fib()` the second time, `sum` will be equal to the previous value returned by `fib()`. However, when you put them inside the function, they are **local** to that scope, and at each function invocation they start "fresh" and are re-initialized (technically they have [*automatic storage duration*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration)).

Comment: Oh man, this was it. Thanks for pointing that out. I totally ignored the fact that the variables would keep their values when outside the main. Thanks a ton!